# Selenium Browser Issue

Tags: python, selenium, splinter

So I have been using splinter (wrapper around selenium) to automate a web browser. Recently it stopped working. It opens a browser window but doesn't go to the website.

My code:

```
import splinter
browser=splinter.Browser()
browser.visit('http://google.com')
```

The error I get is :

```
WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile. Profile Dir: c:\users\rbarnes\appdata\local\temp\tmpuaskxw If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.
```

Traceback points to the second line in the code. This worked perfectly fine yesterday.

Comment: Could be due to auto update of Firefox browser. You can try downgrading Firefox to a previous version or upgrading selenium version.

Comment: That worked great thank you Amit!